# Array length undefined

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, variable-length

I'm trying to get the length of a multidimensional Array as follows, but when I test it with `alert()` I get undefined. I would like to know how many items has the parent array (myArray), as I would like then to use it in a cycle `i=0;i<myArray.length;i++`.

Any ideas?

```
myArray = array = {
        'def':array = {
            "first":"value",
        },
        0 : array = {
            "T":"Some text",
        },
        1 : array = {
            "T":"Some text",
        },
};

leng = myArray.length;
alert(leng);
```

Comment: You are creating an object not an array..

Comment: See [Length of Javascript Object (ie. Associative Array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array) for deriving the length of an object/associative

Comment: I don't see any Array in your code. Your `myArray` *object* does not have a `length` property

Comment: That's not an object either, well it is but it doesn't contain the values you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array using array syntax:

```
    array = ["first item", {second:'item'}, 3];
    array.def = {something:"else"};
    alert(array.length);
```

And here's how you create a multidimensional array using an array of arrays:

```
    array = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ];

    alert(array[0][2]); // alerts "3"
```