# What to use instead of Object.keys()?

Tags: jquery

I need to find something in Jquery that can work in IE8 as well as real browsers. I'm brand new to Jquery, the following is my code that works in modern browsers:

```
$('#FIELD_'+office_id).on('change',function(){
    offices = $(this).val();
for(var i=0; i<=Object.keys(southland.address).length;i++){
        if(offices == Object.keys(southland.address)[i]){
            address = southland.address[offices]Object.keys(southland.address[offices])[0]];
        }
    }
```

where southland.address comes from an external array. This works perfect in Chrome, IE10 and FF, anything I can do for IE8?

Comment: what happens with this code in IE8? Does it throw any error, or it simply doesn't work silently?

Comment: There is a syntax error in line 5 of this code near  `offices]Object.keys`

Comment: Precisely, it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Just polyfill `Object.keys`  https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To support Object.keys in older browsers, you can use this snippet:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');

      var result = [];

      for (var prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) result.push(prop);
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (var i=0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) result.push(dontEnums[i]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  })();
}
```

or this polyfill (which includes other shims, as well):

https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/

Comment: Does this code need to go in a specific place? Thanks so much.

Comment: It should appear above the first instance of you using Object.keys, but preferably it should go in a "polyfills" area of your scripts (where you may put other shims/plugins/utilities, etc)

Comment: Thank you. Case of wordpress you can easily add it to main.js at your current theme folder.