# How do I count json items?

Tags: jquery, json

How do I count the number of items in my json feed?

Abbreviated json format...

```
{
    "rlm1":[...],
    "rlm2":[...],
    "rlm3":[...],
    "rlm4":[...]
}
```

jquery...

```
$.getJSON("jsondata.js", function(data) {
    alert(data.length); //returns undefined, expecting 4
}
```

I feel like more is needed at the top of the json file. I can reformat my json file if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Object.keys` in a modern browser.

```
$.getJSON("jsondata.js", function(data) {
    alert(Object.keys(data).length);
}
```

In an older browser either use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) or underscore's [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys).

Comment: +1 Good solution. As a small addition, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818430/what-to-use-instead-of-object-keys#answer-17818507) provides a good reference on how to polyfill this functionality in browsers that do not support `Object.keys` natively...

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere What is `d`?

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere Please, demonstrate a working instance. That answer only appears to apply to ASP.NET

Comment: But now I see something, you're using $.getJson so I don't know if it applies, I usually use $.ajax

Comment: Would reformatting my json eliminate the need Object.keys? What if I started my json with { "matchups" : [... or something like that where I could then refer to matchups.length. Would something like that do it too?

Comment: @Blazemonger, you're right, that only works for ASP.NET. I rectify my answer, although it's useful to know if anyone as to work with ASP.NET per chance